# Apollyon and The Forgotten's pages have gone blank?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth+

In new game the pages for Apollyon and The Forgotten have gone completely blank.

Here's The Forgotten's page:

> [image]

Here's Apollyon's page:

> [image]

Even the starting item text has gone missing.

How can I fix this?

Maybe this is related:
https://steamcommunity.com/app/250900/discussions/0/142260718946072662/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an answer on the [Steam Forums](https://steamcommunity.com/app/250900/discussions/0/1768134097433578287/)

> The "old man" was the red herring sprite for the Keeper, intended for dataminers. We're the 1st of April today, so this skin is used for the Keeper instead of its usual one.
>   Apparently, Nicalis did a "meh" job on that and didn't update it correctly for AB+. That's why AB+ characters are invisible in the menu.
>
> Overall, no relation to Antibirth at all. Nothing special to fix, all will be back to normal tomorrow.